# How to loop through columns of a data.frame and use a function

Tags: r, function, scope

This has probably been answered already and in that case, I am sorry to repeat the question, but unfortunately, I couldn't find an answer to my problem. I am currently trying to work on the readability of my code and trying to use functions more frequently, yet I am not that familiar with it.

I have a `data.frame` and some columns contain `NA`'s that I want to interpolate with, in this case, a simple kalman filter.

```
require(imputeTS)

#some test data
col <- c("Temp","Prec")
df_a <- data.frame(c(10,13,NA,14,17),
                   c(20,NA,30,NA,NA))
names(df_a) <- col

#this is my function I'd like to use
gapfilling <- function(df,col){
  print(sum(is.na(df[,col])))
  df[,col] <- na_kalman(df[,col])
}

#this is my for-loop to loop through the columns
for (i in col) {
  gapfilling(df_a, i)
}
```

I have two problems:

1. My for loop works, yet it doesn't overwrite the `data.frame`. Why?
2. How can I achieve this without a `for-loop`? As far as I am aware you should avoid `for-loops` if possible and I am sure it's possible in my case, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. How can I achieve this without a `for-loop`? As far as I am aware you should avoid `for-loops` if possible and I am sure it's possible in my case, I just don't know how.

You most definitely do not have to avoid `for loops`. What you should avoid is using a loop to perform actions that could be vectorized. Loops are in general just fine, however they are (much) slower compared to compiled languages such as [c++](http://www.cplusplus.com/), but are equivalent to loops in languages such as [python](https://www.python.org/).

1. My for loop works, yet it doesn't overwrite the `data.frame`. Why?

This is a problem with overwriting values within a function, or what is referred to as [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). Basically any assignment is restricted to its current environment (or scope). Take the example below:

```
f <- function(x){
    a <- x
    cat("a is equal to ", a, "\n")
    return(3)
}
x <- 4
f(x)
a is equal to  4 
[1] 3
print(a)
```

> Error in print(a) : object 'a' not found

As you can see, "a" definitely exists, but it stops existing after the function call has been fulfilled. It is restricted to the `environment` (or `scope`) of the function. Here the scope is basically the time at which the function is run.

To alleviate this, you have to overwrite the value in the global environment

```
for (i in col) {
  df_a[, i] <- gapfilling(df_a, i)
}
```

Now for readability (not speed) one could change this to a `lapply`

```
df_a[, col] <- lapply(df_a[, col], na_kalman)
```

I set a heavy point on it not being faster than using a loop. `lapply` iterates over each column, as you would in a loop. Speed could be obtained if say `na_kalman` was programmed to take multiple columns, and possibly save time using optimized `c` or `c++` code.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain basic's in R. I like the `lapply` approach due to it's readability. Would it also be possible to use my gapfilling function in combination with `lapply`? I don't understand how the dimensions would be passed to the function in the right order, and basic `apply` tutorials in the internet do not help there.

Comment: No problem. In most cases it is a question to simply change the function, so that the input is a single column instead of the entire `data.frame` with and index. `gapfilling2 <- function(col){ .... }` at which point it would simply replace `na_kalman` in the `lapply` call. Alternatively using `lapply(col, function(x) gapfilling(df_a, x))` can be used. Here `function(x) gapfilling(df_a, x)` becomes the function call of `lapply` and it would then iterate over the columns specified in `col`.

Comment: Note in the latter my last coding example would be `df_a[, col] <- lapply(col, function(x) gapfilling(df_a, x))`.